# If the main function never returns in iOS, why return anything anyway?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "WhereamiAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([WhereamiAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Upon closer inspection on UIApplicationMain function it states "Despite the declared return type, this function never returns"

Why does main try to return the integer value from this function if it never returns?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Objective C standard is based on the C standard. C standard explicitly prohibits a `main` that returns `void`. Only these two signatures are allowed:

```
int main()
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

In order to comply with this standard, the `main` must be declared as returning an integer. The return value does not matter, but it must be present (C99 standard allows omitting the `return` statement in `main`).

Since `UIApplicationMain` never returns, the following would be valid as well:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([WhereamiAppDelegate class]));
    }
    // This line is never reached, and C99 standard allows omitting it,
    // so you can safely remove the return statement below:
    return 0;
}
```